# How to code a method to return 2 different arrays to another class?

Tags: java, arrays

i have a code with 4 class, Deck, Card, Player and Test.

My idea is create a blackjack game where a Player have your "hands" with cards provided by deck.
My code is working, but i want only 1 method to return 2 different arrays.

*Resume of my code:*

**Card:** a card(value,suit)

**Deck:** create a array of cards with 52 cards. a class with method provideCards() to get cards for players.

**Player:** a class with array of cards "hands"

*Where is the problem?*

Look the class "Deck" i'm using 2 methods, provideCards() and provideNewCards(), both methods are equals however returning different arrays for each player.
I can't use in my method provideCards() " ArrayList player = new ArrayList<>();
" because i need save my old array to add a new card before. How can I code only 1 method to return 1 array of "hands" for each player?

My code:

**Deck Class:**

```
    package jamilzin.cassino;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

 // /*
   public class Deck {
    private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
    public  ArrayList<Card> playerA = new ArrayList<>();
    public  ArrayList<Card> playerB = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<String> suits = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(" Diamonds", " Clubs", " Spades", " Hearts"));
    Random gerador = new Random();
    
    public Deck(){
  for(int j=0; j<suits.size(); j++){ // Idea: create a 13 cards for each suits
      for(int i=0; i<13; i++){ 
 deck.add(new Card((i + 1), suits.get(j))); 
    } // for i
  } // for j
   Collections.shuffle(deck); // randomize the deck
} // deck()
    
public ArrayList<Card> provideCards(){
   int  number = gerador.nextInt(52);
   while(deck.get(number)==null){ 
        number = gerador.nextInt(52);}
   Card card = (deck.get(number));
  playerA.add(card);
   deck.set(number, null);
        return  playerA ;} 

public ArrayList<Card> provideNewCards(){
   int  number = gerador.nextInt(52);
   while(deck.get(number)==null){ 
        number = gerador.nextInt(52);}
   Card card = (deck.get(number));
  playerB.add(card);
   deck.set(number, null);
        return  playerB ;} 


@Override
public String toString(){
    return deck.toString();
    }   
   }
```

**Card Class:**

```
package jamilzin.cassino;

public class Card {
    
    private String suit;
    private int value;
    
    Card(int value, String suit){
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
     return getValue() + getSuit();
    //return Integer.toString(getValue());
}
}
```

**Player Class:**

```
package jamilzin.cassino;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Player {
 ArrayList<Card>  hands = new ArrayList<>();

 
   public Player(){
this.hands = new ArrayList<>();
    }

   
    public ArrayList<Card> getHands() {
    return hands;
    }
    
    public void setHands(ArrayList<Card> hands) {
        this.hands = hands;
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
package jamilzin.cassino;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Cassino {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 Deck deckMaster = new Deck();
Player PlayerA = new Player();
Player PlayerB = new Player();
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
 PlayerA.setHands(deckMaster.provideCards());}
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
PlayerB.setHands(deckMaster.provideNewCards());}

        System.out.println(PlayerA.getHands());
        System.out.println(PlayerB.getHands());
        
        System.out.println(deckMaster);
    }
 }
```

class Test results: [Run Project result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2gnj.png)

Comment: You'll have to make a class to hold those two arrays, and return an instance of that.  That's pretty much how it works in Java.

Comment: Java is good to pratice? @LouisWasserman or JS is better?

Comment: There is no useful way to answer that question.

Comment: @jamilzin you can use a `Pair<>` of both components or an array with two entries to return different items at once. Still there are some better ways that needs big changes in your code, so I would recommend the array.

Answer (score 0):

Enum Suit

```
public enum Suit {
    DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES, HEARTS
}
```

Cassino

```
public class Cassino {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blackjack game = new Blackjack(2);

        System.out.println(game);
    }
}
```

Blackjack

```
public class Blackjack {
    private final Player[] players;
    private final Deck deck;

    public Blackjack(int player) {
        this.players = createPlayer(player);
        this.deck = new Deck();
    }

    public Player[] createPlayer(int player){
        Player[] players = new Player[player];
        for (int i = 0; i < player; i++) {
            List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                cards.add(deck.provideCard());
            }
            players[i] = new Player(cards);
        }
        return players;
    }

    public Player[] getPlayers() {
        return players.clone();
    }

    public Deck getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Blackjack{" +
                "players=" + Arrays.toString(players) +
                ", deck=" + deck +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Deck

```
public class Deck {
    private final LinkedList<Card> deck;

    public Deck() {
        Suit[] suits = Suit.values();
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Suit suit : suits) { // Idea: create a 13 cards for each suits
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                cards.add(new Card((j + 1), suit));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards); // randomize the deck
        deck = new LinkedList<>(cards) {
        };
    } // deck()

    public Card provideCard() {
        return deck.pollFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Deck{" +
                "deck=" + deck +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Card

```
    public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final int value;

    Card(int value, Suit suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValue() + getSuit().toString();
        //return Integer.toString(getValue());
    }
}
```

Player

```
    public class Player {
    List<Card> hand;

    public Player(List<Card> cards) {
        this.hand = cards;
    }


    public List<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public void setHand(List<Card> hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public void addToHand(Card card){
        this.hand.add(card);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "hand=" + hand +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### Some Recommendations

1. Use the more general type for your variables and methods as you can, because it doesn't change the logic if you would use an LinkedList instaed
2. You don't need Random because your deck is already shuffeld so you don't need to get a random one of the shuffeld list.  Instead you should use a explicit LinkedList this will offer you the methode pollFirst which polls out the first/head of the list and reduce the list aka you deck.
3. Suits should be an Enum and not a List of strings because it is a not changing enumeration. So new Enum Suits.
4. Is there a reason why the hand of the players should not be in the player class?
5. And you need more classes to give the game a structure for the logic and things like that